# Global variable across multiple Rule tables in a Decision table

Tags: drools, xls

I have 5 logical groups of 5 facts each with about 5 rules (rows in my Decision table) All actions are on the same global variable. Now, before I populate the Decision table with a 125 row by 50 column matrix I'd like to understand if I can logically separate these 5 groups into 5 10 column 25 row Rule Tables all with the same global variable named? Will they use the same global variable that I can reference after firing?

Also something not clear to me because the examples I see are very simple, is can you refer to the imported object in the rule ACTION cell? E.g.

```
ACTION
netincome = user.gross_household_income - $1 - $2 - $3
Net Income
0, (user.gross_household_income – 816400) * 0.12, 0
(user.gross_household_income – 1150000) * 0.30, (user.gross_household_income – 816400) * 0.12, 0
```

Comment: The code sample doesn't make sense - it isn't syntactically correct. You need to have some valid Java statement(s).

Comment: I don't understand the question. The documentation makes it pretty clear what results from a decision table, no matter what the number of rows and columns. And it also clearly says that whatever is in one decision table will be in one generated DRL file. So ... ?

Comment: OK, I get it now. I was not familiar with drl file or their scope. I will split the class I populate into 5 classes and each will be a global variable for each of the 5 groups.

Comment: Regarding the syntax, I have not shown the declared class used in the rules, but user is a field in that class and gross_household_income is a field in the user class, so my reading of the documentation suggests it uses reflection to fetch the values from the instance of the class passed in. Is that not correct? My question relates to the use of reflection in the actual rules cells.

Comment: Your comments don't relate my comments #1 and #2. Your #1 confuses matters even more since I don't know what the "class I populate" is and how you split. Why mention this at all? Your #2 it raises an entirely different question.

Comment: Your comment #2 states one decision table is one drl file, which has it's own scope. Since I had one global variable in a single class this could not have been shared across those 5 drl files. So I split it into 5 classes each one specific to a drl file. That is how you helped me.

Comment: The syntax question is simply because the documentation is poor here. It states "From the fourth row on, non-blank entries provide data for interpolation as described above" for both CONDITION and ACTION. What is data here? A literal only? or can Drools use reflection to obtain a value from a field in the instance of the class used in the condition or a global variable? Examples in the documentation show only literals

Comment: Is the term "interpolation" baffling you? AFAIK, (apart from the purely mathematical usage) it means to "insert text into another text". Thus "data" is some text, whatever it is. The composition of rule text is just text processing, akin to macro expansion. --- I'm not sure whether using references to other fields of some fact would be a good idea as a "data value" to be inserted. I cannot say from the single example you have provided what you might want to vary across rows. Will it be completely different expressions or just different numeric values? - Decision tables are frequently misused.